# How to pass OAuth Client Credentials to a WebClient dynamically with Spring Security 5?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm developing a generic web client wrapper which should send requests to a OAuth2 protected resource. My idea was to implement a ClientWrapper which holds a `WebClient`. The ClientWrapper offers methods to access the resource like getFile(String registrationId). I thought I could register different `ClientRegistration` at runtime and obtain them with the `WebClient`.

So far I've registered a `WebClient` as follows:
ClienRegistration Bean:

```
@Bean
    public ClientRegistration clientRegistration() {
        ClientRegistration.Builder clientRegestrationBuilder = ClientRegistration
                .withRegistrationId(CLIENT_REGISTRATION_ID);
        clientRegestrationBuilder.clientId(CLIENT_ID);
        clientRegestrationBuilder.clientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET);
        clientRegestrationBuilder.tokenUri(TOKEN_ENDPOINT);
        clientRegestrationBuilder.authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS);

        return clientRegestrationBuilder.build();
    }
```

In memory holder:

```
@Bean
    public ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations(List<ClientRegistration> clientRegistrations) {
        return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistrations);
    }
```

Web Client Builder

```
    @Bean(OAUTH2_WEB_CLIENT)
    public WebClient oauthFilteredWebClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrationRepository,
                new UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository());
        return WebClient.builder().filter(oauth).build();
    }
```

I've injected it into my ClientWrapper:

```
public ClientWrapper(WebClient webClient) {
    this.webClient = webClient;
}

@Override
public File getFile(String regId) {
    Mono<File> result = webClient.get().uri("https://somepath") //
            .attributes(ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction
                    .clientRegistrationId(regId))
            .retrieve() //
            .bodyToMono(File.class);
    return result.block();
}
```

Doing it this way it is very static and I'm only able to use exactly one OAuth2 client (clientid/client-secret and token endpoint). With the idea providing a registration id it would be needed to register n `ClientRegistration` objects at runtime which I think is not possible and doesn't feel right... Is there a nice way to pass a "OAuthCredentials" object to a `WebClient` dynamically which is used for fetching a token?